# Как работает удаление? Что может стать причиной удаления сообщения и что представляет собой процесс удаления? Каковы критерии для удаления?

Tags: поддержка, faq, удаление-вопросов, удаление-ответов

При каких условиях происходит удаление вопросов и ответов, и что представляет собой процесс удаления?

- Как можно удалить сообщение?
- Когда я *не* могу удалить свое сообщение?
- Можно ли увидеть список своих удаленных сообщений?
- Как можно восстановить свое удаленное сообщение?
- Что означает удаление применительно к сообщению?
- Как голоса влияют на удаление?
- Каковы критерии для удаления?
- Что еще следует знать об удалении?
- Что произойдет, если я поставлю “тревогу” в своем сообщении с запросом на удаление?

> Подробнее, см. статьи про [удаленные вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions) и [удаленные ответы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers) в [справке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: Такое ощущение, что где-то я это уже читал...

Answer (score 11):

## Как можно удалить сообщение?

#### Удаление участником:

1. Как правило, **вы** можете самостоятельно удалять свои сообщения; исключения перечислены ниже, в разделе «Когда я *не* могу удалить свое сообщение?». Для удаления сообщения нажмите ссылку «удалить», которая находится под сообщением.
2. **Модераторы** могут сразу удалить любое сообщение.
3. **Участники с репутацией >= 2000** (точнее, с привилегией «[Редактировать вопросы и ответы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit)»; 1000 на бета-сайтах) [могут запросить автоматическое удаление сообщения, если выбирают пункт «рекомендовать удаление» из очереди правки сообщений с низким качеством](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/145292/152859).
4. **Участники с репутацией >= 10 000** (точнее, с привилегией «[инструменты модератора](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/privileges/moderator-tools)»; 2000 на бета-сайтах) могут проголосовать за удаление *вопросов*, которые были [закрыты/приостановлены](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) в течение 48 часов. Для удаления требуется 3 голоса; [или больше, если вопрос является популярным](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50523/should-delete-votes-be-limited-like-close-votes/51071#51071), но не более 10 голосов.
5. **Участники с репутацией >= 20 000** (точнее, с привилегией «[проверенный участник](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/privileges/trusted-user)»; 4000 на бета-сайтах) могут не дожидаться окончания периода в 48 часов для удаления закрытых вопросов с рейтингом -3 или ниже. Также они могут удалять  *ответы* с рейтингом -1 или ниже. Для удаления ответа требуется 3 голоса.

#### Удаление системой:

6. [Система](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/who-is-the-community-user) автоматически удаляет любое сообщение с 6 [тревогами](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22174/how-does-the-offensive-flag-work-in-stackoverflow) за агрессию или спам.
7. Система [автоматически удаляет](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/auto-deleting-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006) закрытые (не являющиеся дубликатами), незаблокированные вопросы с нулевым или отрицательным рейтингом, на которые не получено ответов с положительными голосами или принятых ответов, или не имеющих голосов за повторное открытие; вопросы, закрытые 9 дней назад или ранее и вопросы которые не редактировались в течение последних 9 дней.
8. Система автоматически удаляет [незаблокированные вопросы с отрицательным рейтингом, на которые не было получено ответов, через 30 дней](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/auto-deleting-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006).
9. Система автоматически удаляет [незаблокированные вопросы с нулевым рейтингом (или с рейтингом 1, если профиль владельца вопроса был удален), на которые не было получено ответов и которые в среднем имеют менее 1,5 просмотров в день и менее 2 комментариев, через 365 дней](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/auto-deleting-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006).
10. Система автоматически удаляет все вопросы с отрицательным рейтингом (и ответы на эти вопросы) и ответы с отрицательным рейтингом при удалении учетной записи их владельцев.
11. Система автоматически удаляет все вопросы, перенесенные на другие сайты, [через 30 дней](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79051/why-was-my-question-moved-and-why-was-it-then-deleted-off-of-the-original-site/79082#79082). Примечание: это относится только к исходному вопросу на исходном сайте («заглушка при переносе»), а не к вопросу, который заново создается на другом сайте в результате переноса. Вопросы, автоматически удаленные по этому критерию, не утрачивают историю правки, которая видна всем, а ссылки на эти вопросы ведут на новый вопрос, а не на страницу ошибки.
12. Вопросы и ответы, на которые получено шесть правок «Рекомендуется удаление» в очереди правок сообщений низкого качества, автоматически удаляются «при редактировании». Сообщения попадают в эту очередь либо автоматически, либо при получении определенных тревог (тревоги очень низкого качества у вопросов и тревоги очень низкого качества и несоответствия ответа вопросу для ответов) и могут быть извлечены из очереди при получении достаточного количества отзывов «Полезное сообщение».

## Когда я *не* могу удалить свое сообщение?

Вы не можете удалить [принятые](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/accepting-answers-what-is-it-all-about) *ответы*.

Нельзя удалить *свой вопрос* если:

- на него дан [ответ с положительными голосами](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74466/does-systematic-self-deleting-need-to-be-prevented/74471#74471);
- на него дан принятый ответ;
- на него дано несколько ответов (даже если у них нет положительных голосов).

Вы не можете удалить *любой* из ваших вопросов, если вы не имеете *зарегистрированной* учетной записи (т.е. записи, связанной с OpenID).

## Можно ли увидеть список своих удаленных сообщений?

Да, но в нем будут только [удаленные сообщения, которые были созданы **за последние 60 суток**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185491/what-is-the-deleted-recent-questions-page-in-the-user-profile). Полный список удаленных сообщений [скорее всего будет недоступен](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted).

## Как можно восстановить свое удаленное сообщение?

Изначальный автор сообщения может просмотреть и восстановить его, если он его удалил. Но автор не может редактировать удаленный им вопрос, пока он его не восстановит. Автор может редактировать удаленный им ответ без восстановления. Обычно, если ваше удаленное сообщение было удалено не вами, самостоятельно восстановить его нельзя (но, возможно, вы сможете проголосовать за его восстановление). Исключение: если ответ удален из очереди правки сообщений низкого качества голосами "Рекомендуется удаление" без голосов трех проверенных участников, голосующих за удаление, он [может быть восстановлен](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228479/259867) автором.

Если ваше сообщение было удалено [проверенным участником](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/privileges/trusted-user), для его восстановления потребуется три голоса за восстановление - набрать требуемые голоса можно с помощью вежливой просьбы на Мета-сайте, если вы сможете привести хорошую причину для восстановления вопроса.

Если ваше сообщение было удалено модератором, вы можете поставить знак тревоги в одно из других своих сообщений и написать примечание в поле «другое», объяснив ситуацию и попросив восстановить сообщение.

Примечание: удаленные вопросы не показываются в результатах поиска, поэтому, если вы хотите позже восстановить вопрос, который вы удалили, вам понадобится где-то найти его сохраненный URL. Участники с репутацией 10 000 и выше также могут отмечать вопросы как «избранные», чтобы позже их можно было найти под вкладкой «Избранное» в своем профиле. Никто, кроме модераторов, не может выполнять поиск удаленных сообщений.

Удаленные сообщения *в течение 60 дней* (начиная с даты создания) находятся в списках [«недавно удаленные вопросы» или «недавно удаленные ответы»](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185492/).

## Что означает удаление применительно к сообщению?

Удаленные сообщения обычно **не** удаляются физически (в значении удаления из системы); они просто спрятаны (т.н «мягкое удаление»). Это означает, что они не показываются в результатах поиска или в дампе данных, а участники, пытающиеся просмотреть их по ссылке, увидят страницу [404 (не найдено) с причиной удаления](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1).

Модераторы и участники с репутацией 10 000 и выше могут просмотреть все удаленные сообщения, на которые у них есть ссылка. Модераторы могут восстановить любое удаленное сообщение.

«Участники с репутацией 10 000» могут голосовать за восстановление удаленных  *вопросов*; обычно требуется три голоса для восстановления вопроса, но иногда [требуется больше голосов](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/51071/259867).

«Участники с репутацией 20 000» также могут голосовать за восстановление удаленных *ответов*; для восстановления ответа требуется три голоса.

## Что еще следует знать об удалении?

- Изменения репутации вследствие вознаграждений, голосов (за и против) и принятия сообщений, связанные с удаленными сообщениями (включая ответы на удаленные сообщения), обнуляются. (Исключение: репутация, полученная за сообщения с рейтингом три и выше, с условием, что сообщение отображалось на сайте не менее 60 дней, [сохраняется](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/reputation-and-historical-archives/)).
- Репутация, вычтенная в качестве штрафа за удаление сообщения путем голосования, не возвращается.
- В первый раз, когда вы удаляете свое сообщение с рейтингом три и выше, вы получаете [знак «Дисциплинированный»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/badges/37/disciplined).
- В первый раз, когда вы удаляете свое сообщение с рейтингом минус три и ниже, вы получаете [знак «Давление сообщества»](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/badges/38/peer-pressure).
- Ответы удаляются автоматически при удалении вопроса, к которому они принадлежат. Такие ответы автоматически восстанавливаются при восстановлении вопроса, кроме ответов, удаленных *до* удаления вопроса.

## Как работают голоса за удаление?

- Если вы обладаете [привилегией голосования за удаление (часть привилегии «инструменты модератора»)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/privileges/moderator-tools) (репутация 10 000 на рабочих сайтах, 2000 на бета-сайтах), у вас есть 5 голосов за удаление в день, [плюс 1 голос за каждые 1000 очков репутации выше 10 000](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79015/now-that-20k-users-can-delete-answers-should-we-increase-the-number-of-daily-de/105876#105876) ([не более 30 голосов в день](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5212/what-are-the-limits-on-how-i-can-cast-change-and-retract-votes)). Голоса за удаление своих сообщений [могут входить или не входить в предельное количество голосов](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274757/3717023), в зависимости от обстоятельств.
- Количество голосов за восстановления равно количеству голосов за удаление.

  *Голоса за удаление или за восстановление не имеют сроков давности.

## Каковы критерии для удаления?

Относительно вопросов, удаляются сообщения, которые [не добавляют *ничего* нового на сайт](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/59054/148099).  В основном это касается большинства закрытых вопросов, которые нельзя улучшить и открыть повторно. Но иногда полезно оставить дубликаты вопросов, чтобы облегчить будущим пользователям поиск исходного вопроса.

Относительно ответов, удаляются сообщения, которые [не являются ответами](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/163733/148099) (должны быть оформлены как комментарий, не отвечают на вопрос, и пр.). Неверные ответы и ответы с плохими советами не удаляются, за них следует отдавать отрицательные голоса.

## Что произойдет, если я поставлю «тревогу» в своем сообщении с запросом на удаление?

Обычно модераторы отклоняют такие тревоги по следующим причинам:

- Если вы можете удалить вопрос самостоятельно  (так как на него не получено ответов или у единственного ответа нет положительных голосов), сделайте это сами. Эта ситуация не требует вмешательства модератора.
- Если вы не можете удалить свой вопрос, скорее всего за него проголосовали или дали несколько ответов. Удаление вопроса также удаляет и ответы. Удаление ответов сводит на нет работу тех, кто отвечал на ваш вопрос и они теряют репутацию, полученную за эти ответы. Это несправедливо по отношению к авторам ответов.

Если вы отправили вопрос, о котором вы потом раскаиваетесь по следующим причинам:

- это школьное задание и вы нарушаете «правила поведения» школы;
- это глупый вопрос и вам за него стыдно.

В этом случае, удаление вопросов не поможет, так как участники с репутацией 10 000 (2000 на бета-сайтах) все равно будут его видеть. Также в [(разделе 3) Условий обслуживания четко указано](http://stackexchange.com/legal), что (свободный перевод, смотрите оригинал по ссылке):

> Вы подтверждаете, что все содержание подписчика, которое Вы передаете в Сеть, бессрочно и неотзывно разрешается для публикации Stack Exchange в рамках лицензии Creative Commons Attribution Share Alike. Вы даете Stack Exchange бессрочное и неотзывное разрешение и право использовать, копировать, сохранять, публиковать, отображать, распространять, изменять, создавать производные материалы и хранить такое содержание подписчика ...

Модераторы не будут удалять ваш вопрос по указанным выше причинам.

*Что, если я передал в сообщении код моего работодателя, защищенный законом об авторском праве, или в моем вопросе содержится нарушение авторского права и по требованиям законодательства он должен быть удален?*

Компания Stack Exchange воспользуется процедурой удаления контента в соответствии с Законом об авторском праве в цифровую эпоху (DMCA). Если вы являетесь владельцем контента, защищенного законом об авторском праве, и кто-либо (например, ваш работник) написал сообщение с содержимым, которое нарушает ваше авторское право, вы можете отправить запрос на удаление такого содержимого, после чего оно будет удалено. Эта процедура [описана в разделе 15 условий обслуживания](http://stackexchange.com/legal).

Не следует отмечать «тревогой» ваш вопрос для привлечения внимания модератора.

*Существуют ли исключения?*

Иногда бывают исключения из этих правил. Зачастую, они происходят при следующих условиях:

- все ответы были оставлены более 60 дней назад и имеют низкий балл, или не имеют баллов (те, кто оставил эти ответы, не теряют репутацию за ответы, так как репутация, полученная 60 дней назад или ранее не снимается при удалении сообщения, если сообщение набрало 3 и более баллов)
- В вопросах и ответах есть что-то подозрительное, что не относится к пунктам, перечисленным в данном ответе.

---

Свободный перевод публикации «[How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/)».

Comment: Участники с репутацией 10 000 и выше теперь могут найти все свои удалённые вопросы (и ответы) посредством поиска `deleted:1`. Это было введено [недавно](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/270562) и ещё не отражено в публикации-источнике.

Comment: *Участники с репутацией 10 000 и выше также могут отмечать вопросы как «избранные»* — по-моему, это могут делать **все** участники вне зависимости от репутации.