# Содержательный ответ удалён как «В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса»

Tags: обсуждение

У вопроса [Просмотр компьютеров в локальной сети из терминала Linux](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/541699/23044) был [удалён ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/701555/23044), который предлагает [nbtscan](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man1/nbtscan.1.html) решение, которое вполне является ответом на возможную интерпретацию фразы *«увидеть остальные компьютеры внутри сети»* (шаг в поиске Samba шар). Принятый ответ использует `nmap -sn` (ping).

[Принятая политика](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2293/23044):

> Относительно ответов, удаляются сообщения, которые не являются ответами (должны быть оформлены как комментарий, не отвечают на вопрос, и пр.). Неверные ответы и ответы с плохими советами не удаляются, за них следует отдавать отрицательные голоса.

Если вы считаете в ответе не хватает подробностей, то оставьте соответствующий комментарий (с упоминанием каких именно подробностей не хватает). Если вы считаете ответ неверным, поставьте минус. Не нужно удалять.

Comment: [Релевантная проверка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/187221).

Comment: Предлагаю забанить всех удаляторов. 

Comment: @Squidward: это неправильный подход. Не ошибается только тот, кто ничего не делает.

Comment: Там ответ был оформлен так, что без бутылки не разберешься о чем отвечающий написал.

Comment: @Squidward их бы как-нибудь призвать в обсуждение и выяснить причину, по которой они удаление рекомендовали.