# Вопрос достоин ответа, но не достоин голоса

Tags: обсуждение, голоса-за

Часто наблюдаю за следующим явлением: участник тратит своё время на Ответ, причем иногда вполне серьезный, при этом не считает нужным проголосовать за Вопрос, на который дал Ответ. Забывает :) ?

А Вы как считаете, почему?

Comment: Вы задаете вопросы ради плюсика? Или ради ответа всё-таки?

Comment: "Вопрос отражает стремление разобраться; он понятен и несет пользу" - я не обязан считать что это так, чтобы дать ответ. Скажите спасибо, что минус не поставили :)

Comment: Например, ждёт что автор вопроса примет ответ, поставит плюс или хоть как-то откомментирует. А то часто получается игра в одни ворота — и ответ написал, и вопрос плюсанул, а в ответ — тишина. А так плюс вопросу используется в качестве поощрения за активность автора вопроса.

Comment: @NickVolynkin: очень интересная стратегия. Но разве когда мы отвечаем, мы не отвечаем сразу всем тем, на будущее, кто столкнется с этим вопросом?

Comment: @TimurVI и от всех ждём плюсов :)

Comment: @TimurVI, да, но принять ответ может только автор, ну или прокомментировать если что-то не устроило

Comment: Я считаю, что плюс вопросу означает, что вопрос интересный и заслуживает м.б. нескольких ответов, т.е. плюс призывает остальных участников посмотреть на этот вопрос.

Answer (score 18):

Я отвечаю, если могу это сделать. Но это не означает, что вопрос мне нравится. Я бы сказал, что эти вещи никак не связаны.

Могу плюсануть вопрос, который мне понравился, но не могу на него ответить (например, не хватает знаний).

С другой стороны, если есть какой-то тривиальный вопрос, с которым я могу помочь, но который, по сути, не интересный/скучный. За него я вряд ли буду голосовать.

Answer (score 14):

Если меня спросить почему небо синее, я отвечу. Может быть даже очень подробно, с уходом в биологию глаза и физику рэлеевского рассеяния. Но вопроса не оценю. А если автору вопроса больше 10 лет, то ещё и осудить могу.

Если же вопрос будет действительно глубоким, сложным и интересным, если мне самому, для того чтобы дать ответ, придётся искать информацию и разбираться в ней, то я посчитаю автора вопроса человеком умным, а его вопрос полезным для общества и заслуживающим оценки.

Comment: 10 лет - как-то мало, у нас вон народ до сих пор верит (и других учит), что яблоки железом окисляются.

Comment: @Other и что земля плоская. Но на мой взгляд 10 - это уже много.

Comment: Для рэлеевского рассеивания таки мало :)

Comment: Ну ладно вам! «Почему небо голубое?» — отличный пример неплохого новичкового вопроса.

Comment: @VladD, вообще-то я бы и минусанул такому вопросу. Не за плохость (отличный вопрос!), а за неумение гуглить.

Comment: про 10 лет, к чему сказано, не ясно. К примеру, Эйнштейну больше 10 лет было когда он с этой темой работал. Вопрос замечательный: легко понять, существует краткий содержательный ответ, вводящий понятия, полезные и в куче других вещей.

Comment: @jfs я очень надеялся, что мой образный текст не будят понят буквально. Тщетно!

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev вы можете думать что читатели сами виноваты, что ваши мысли не умеют читать, или просто отредактировать ответ и яснее выразиться. Выбор ваш.

Answer (score 8):

Хороший вопрос. Он подтолкнул меня задуматься зачем вообще голосовать за *вопросы*, как люди голосуют, как было бы полезно голосовать.

Голоса и ответы это [почти] независимые понятия. Оба призваны улучшить сайт (повысить [качество знаний](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4181/23044)), но по-разному.

*Ответ о том, **что** вопрос спрашивает. Голосование о том, **как** вопрос был задан.* К примеру, форматирование кода (если вопрос и так ясен) никак не изменяет ответ, но неряшливость вопроса может повлиять на голосование. Публикация ответа и голосование за вопрос относятся к разным областям: в одном случае нужна шапка специалиста в предметной области, в другом — шапка модератора (не требует специфичных технических знаний, относящихся к меткам в вопросе в большинстве случаев, требует знание сайта/сообщества).

В целом голоса на вопросах гораздо менее полезны относительно ответов. Если у вас достаточно репутации, то минусы на вопросы ставить практически бесполезно: если вы считаете, что вопросу не место на сайте —  голосуйте за закрытие. Если вопрос подходящий, но хромает, улучшите его: задавайте уточняющие комментарии, вносите правки.

Польза от плюсов на вопросах:

- индикация другим участникам, что на вопрос можно и стоит ответить. Полезно когда вы прочли, поняли вопрос, но не можете сейчас ответить (не знаете как, или другим участникам хотите возможность оставить). [Создание конкурса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty), цель которого привлечь дополнительное внимание к вопросу, можно рассматривать как супер-голос
- индикация автору вопроса: продолжай в том же духе. Больше подобных вопросов
- индикация системе — вопрос полезен, [не удалять](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2293/23044) [подобному вопросу есть место на Stack Overflow]
- индикация будущим читателям, что сообщение полезно (что смогут решение найти на странице). Поэтому, я ставлю плюс, если  у меня такой же вопрос [из гугла приземлился] и уже есть ответ, который мне полезен, вне зависимости от других качеств вопроса.

Публикация ответа сама по себе уже все пункты покрывает:

- новый ответ поднимает вопрос в списке активных вопросов, где его другие участники могут увидеть (и ответить)
- автор возможно решение проблемы получает. Сама по себе инициатива новые вопросы задавать
- ответы затрудняют [удаление вопросов](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2293/23044)
- очевидно, что автор ответа полагает, что он содержит решение проблемы [полезен].

Иногда плюс просто показывает, что вопрос интересен (в смысле интересного блог-поста): может не решать сиюминутную проблему, но ответ может помочь при решении других задач. Пример: [Отображение числа 9223372036854775807](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/690856/23044).

#### Подытоживая

Раз ответы и голоса похожие вещи о вопросе говорят, то почему бы всегда плюс вопросу не ставить после публикации ответа?

Я думаю, здесь вопрос в степени уверенности: публикуя ответ, автор может надеяться, что решение может помочь будущим посетителям из гугла (и автору), но это не 100%. С другой стороны, голосуя за вопрос, участник с бо́льшей уверенностью выражает те же пункты: что вопрос не только достоин ответа от самого участника, но и достоин и времени/внимания сообщества в целом. Между этими позициями как правило существует зазор, когда человеку полезно ответить на вопрос, но не следует голосовать за него.

Одно дело сказать [ответив на вопрос]: решение этой проблемы *может* помочь людям (вопрос полезен). Другое [голосом «за»] — я одобряю как суть представленной проблемы,  так и способ, которым она была представлена и рекомендую этот вопрос другим участникам [чтобы ответить на вопрос], а автору — больше таких вопросов задавать.

P.S.

Лично я, *отвечая на вопрос*, думаю в основном о конкретной технической проблеме, представленной в вопросе (часть, которую я люблю) -- роль *специалиста* ("знатока/экcперта"). *Голосуя за вопрос*, приходится думать о сайте в целом (где он сейчас, куда идёт), о людях (критерии успеха более расплывчаты/сложнее задача) -- роль *модератора* (поэтому не всегда когда следует голосовать за вопрос, голосую).

P.P.S.

Стоит заметить, что могут быть люди, которым человеческий аспект более интересен, чем написание  непосредственно кода. Для подобных людей улучшение сайта/сообщества с помощью инструментов модерирования может быть более интересным чем решение очередной индивидуальной проблемы по разработке ПО.

Answer (score 7):

Это не связанные вещи на мой взгляд - интересные и заставляющие задуматься вопросы и вопросы на которые можешь ответить. Можно ответить на тривиальный вопрос начинающего и поставить ему же минус, потому что он почти не пытался разобраться.

Кстати, помню попытки задавать тривиальные вопросы "что такое переменная? что такое функция?" пачками, видимо только ради плюсов. После N вопроса от одного автора начал их просто минусовать.

Поэтому, на мой взгляд, плюсовать вопросы только потому на них ответил - неправильно, это может мотивировать задавать плохие и никому не нужные вопросы только ради репутации.

Comment: полезность вопроса на Stack Overflow измеряется скольким людям ответы на него помогли, а не его сложностью.