# Ответил на вопрос, но не проголосовал за него. Почему?

Tags: обсуждение, голоса-за

Собственно сам вопрос. Почему нет?

Comment: Ждёт плюсика или галочку за ответ, а потом проголосует.

Comment: нет требования голосовать за вопрос при ответе. Иногда вопрос не заслуживает голоса, но ответить не жалко.

Comment: Например, до моей кукушки не доходило поначалу, что, если я отвечаю на вопрос, то я им заинтересовался и логично воткнуть плюс вопросу )

Comment: После того как за вопросы стали начислять 10 очков вместо 5, я почти полностью перестал голосовать за вопросы. До этого голосовал за вопросы часто (40% всех моих голосов — за вопросы)

Comment: @АндрейNOP эти недостойные вопрошатели не достойны репутации достойных отвечателей? :)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, скажем так, большинство вопросов не достойны 10 очков, а меньше я не могу дать

Comment: Возможный дубликат [Вопрос достоин ответа, но не достоин голоса](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6259/%d0%92%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b8%d0%bd-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b8%d0%bd-%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b0)

Comment: @edem, А почему бы и да?)) По-моему, рейтинг отражает *отношение*, а не отметку о действии. Качество и содержание вопроса формируют отношение к нему. Вот плюсик после улучшающей правки - можно понять... или не понять его отсутствие. Но разве факт ответа на вопрос делает *вопрос* качественнее или "приятнее"?

Comment: @edem, А что именно "это"?

Comment: @edem, Хм, ну и? Не очень понятно, как сей факт связан с мнением высказанным мной ранее. Если смысл именно в противоречи мнению - ок, прочтено, принято