# Нужно ли удалять заминусованный вопрос?

Tags: обсуждение

Если вопрос заминусовали но в нем есть активность(ответы, комменты и плюсы) нужно ли его удалять? Ведь, как я понял, минусы указывают на то что вопрос должен быть удален.

Comment: минусы указывают, что вопрос либо ответ нуждаются в улучшении

Comment: Не нужно. Если вопрос подпадёт под [критерии автоматического удаления](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2293/213987) -- он будет удалён системой, а если нет -- значит достоин остаться.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Нет, скорее всего не нужно. Особенно, если люди старались и писали ответы.

Comment: если ответы были заплюсованы, то удалить даже заминусованный вопрос будет проблематично

Comment: `Особенно, если люди старались и писали ответы` - наверное стоит пояснить, что **не любые** ответы, а **хорошие и не оффтопичные**. А то так на вопрос "где купить противозачаточные" с ответами адресов и бабок-целительниц - будет висеть на ресурсе, что как-то не комильфо

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, такой вопрос прибьют как спам ;) Под заминусованными обычно понимаются адекватные вопросы.