# Почему репутация за голоса к вопросу не вычитается при удалении вопроса?

Tags: обсуждение, репутация

Был вопрос, набрал 3 голоса, я его удалил, репутация не отнялась. Так и должно быть?

Comment: Какой вопрос? Ссылочку бы

Comment: Из [справочного вопроса](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2293/): `Исключение: репутация, полученная за сообщения с рейтингом три и выше, с условием, что сообщение отображалось на сайте не менее 60 дней, сохраняется`

Comment: @default locale, хорошо, спасибо. Оформите как ответ

Comment: Пожалуйста! Если подходит, то проще задубликатить

Comment: @default locale, да, да :) отметьте как дубликат