# Удалить нельзя закрыть

Tags: поддержка, вопросы, модерация, удаление-вопросов

Попался [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1068471/%D0%A1%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%8F-%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%81%D0%BE-%D1%88%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8). По виду полный оффтопик, то есть вообще даже не обсуждается. Вопрос: почему такие вопросы сразу не удалять? Ведь ТС не добавит такие данные, которые будут связаны с программированием например.

Вопрос к модераторам, не только к [@AK](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/213987/a-k) (AK, без обид, если вы это будете читать, претензий нет никаких, просто интересно чем руководствовались), - почему нельзя просто удалять такие вопросы. Или же они чистятся потом вечером, например, автоматически. Может я чего-то не знаю или не понимаю, как это работает.

Думал отправить тревогу модератору, но ведь модератор посмотрел уже этот вопрос - у меня возникла дилемма. Буду благодарен если растолкуете, что да как.

P.S. Модераторы спасибо за вашу работу, без вас тут была бы помойка :)

Comment: В итоге вопрос удален 3 голосами обычных участников (не-модераторов). Моим в том числе.

Comment: @insolor, мне кажется я не могу удалять вопросы)

Comment: Напрямую за удаление можно голосовать [после 20к репутации](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user). До этого можно голосовать за удаление через очередь проверок.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вам не видно по таймлайну, что я как раз и хотел сначала удалить.

Но потом восстановил и закрыл. Обьясню, почему. Я не злодей: если кто-то вдруг захотел бы стать добрым самаритятнином и дать по горячим следам ответ в комментариях -- такая возможность оставлена. Ну а вопрос же заминусован - он и так через неделю будет удалён духом сообщества.

> Система автоматически удаляет
>
> а) закрытые (не являющиеся дубликатами), незаблокированные вопросы
>
> б) с нулевым или отрицательным рейтингом,
>
> в) на которые не получено ответов с

[Как работает удаление? Что может стать причиной удаления сообщения и что представляет собой процесс удаления? Каковы критерии для удаления?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2293/213987)

Совсем спам, наркотики, розжиг удаляю сразу.

Мне кажется, это вполне подходящий баланс добра и зла. Будет предложение, как сделать лучше -- пишите.

Answer (score 4):

От себя добавлю кое-что.

AK [ссылочку](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2294/15479) интересную добавил.

> Относительно вопросов, удаляются сообщения, которые не добавляют ничего нового на сайт.

И в [оригинале](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/59054/260198):

> You delete a question when the content no longer adds anything to the site

Я подобные вопросы, которые невозможно поправить, в силу того, что они вообще не соотносятся с тематикой сайта, обычно удаляю, чтобы зря не маячили перед глазами.

> Думал отправить тревогу модератору, но ведь модератор посмотрел уже этот вопрос - у меня возникла дилемма

Тревоги желательно использовать только в случае острой нужды (спам, например). Здесь же вопрос просто является явным оффтопиком, который автоматически будет удалён системой.

Comment: поэтому я тревогу решил не трогать до поры до времени)) тут сначала спросил что и как)) спасибо за предоставленную информацию :)